# Redirect to a different URL only changing the domain name in flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask, http-redirect

I am using Python flask. I have a `POST` request with some payload coming on say:

```
abc.com/hello/hello1
```

I want to redirect this (302) to:

```
xyz.com/hello/hello1
```

only changing the domain name while keeping the remaining part as it is and also the payload. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As per RFC, redirect requests (all 3xx) cannot contain request data or headers. You will miss the payload, supplied via POST in original request.

There are two possible workaround I could think of right away:

1. Give the client new URL, and implement further logic on client side;
2. Create a proxy handler on backend, which will do a request by itself and give the answer back as it's own.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: As per Andrejs Cainikovs's comment below, this would not work for a POST with payload.**

In your endpoint, get the url that was used using `request.url` ([see request API here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.path) for more options). Then you can rewrite it and make a redirect.

```
newUrl = "xyz.com/" + route
return redirect(newUrl, code=302)
```

Comment: I don't know the /hello/hello1/ part beforehand. Whatever is after abc.com, I want to redirect the part to xyz.com

Comment: @OliverBlue Could you get the route using `request.url_rule` or `request.path` or `request.full_path`?

Comment: This will not work. As per RFC, redirect requests does not contain any payload or headers. You will miss the payload, supplied via POST in original request.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Ok, so we need a different approach then.